# How To Change The Number Of Dropdown Items Shown for an Excel VB6 Form Combobox

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

By default a Combobox displays 8 Items in it's Dropdown List

Can anybody point me to some (hopefully MINIMAL) Excel VB6 Code to change this default?

Looks like it will have to include API's

I can find examples for VB6 (
[VB6: Extend number of items in combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282942/vb6-extend-number-of-items-in-combo-box/)), but none specific to an Excel VB6 Form Combobox

Answer (score 4):

Combobox.ListRows Property does the trick